# How to group and count grouped mysql results

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I've been trying and searched for this but I seem unable to fix. Here my screenshot.
[image: group and count grouped mysql results]

Now my issue is I want to group the above results by 'form_class'. In this case, the 2's should be grouped and counted as 2 because there are 2 rows while the 4's as 3 because of the 3 rows returned..

Answer (score 0):

Try Below query

```
SELECT form_class,
       COUNT(*) AS COUNT_FORM_CLASS 
FROM ekwendeni_girls.term_reports
GROUP BY form_class
```

Comment: unknown column 'from_class'

Comment: Change column name to `form_calss` as above @JohnMilo

Comment: I have but its giving me wrong count. Its supped to count '2' for 2 and '3' for 4. Check the image.

Comment: You may used student_id in group also remove student_id from group clause

Comment: Can you add another pic after running my query with output @JohnMilo

Comment: For the love of humanity, please don't request pictures. Just ask for properly formatted data.

Comment: Check you group by clause is not same as mine check my query properly and then check output

Comment: Jay Shankar Gupta, the query is still giving me wrong count. Note that there are more records in the table than in the image. What if you try to create a table like the one in the picture?

Comment: @JhonMilo why don't you add sqlfiddle link with sample data and add expected output